Google Cloud Configure Auth is frozen
I have a pipeline on Bitbucket which deploys an nginx service to the Cloud Run service.
    deploy-cloud-run:
      - step:
          name: Build and Deploy Application
          caches:
            - node
          services:
            - docker
          script:
            # Build the application
            - npm install
            - npm run build
            # Set a couple variables for readability
            - CLI_VERSION=466.0.0
            - CLI_FILENAME=google-cloud-cli-${CLI_VERSION}-linux-x86_64.tar.gz
            # Install Google Cloud CLI
            - curl -o /tmp/google-cloud-cli.tar.gz https://dl.google.com/dl/cloudsdk/channels/rapid/downloads/${CLI_FILENAME}
            - tar -xvf /tmp/google-cloud-cli.tar.gz -C /tmp/
            - /tmp/google-cloud-sdk/install.sh -q
            - source /tmp/google-cloud-sdk/path.bash.inc
            - gcloud -v
            # Authenticating with the service account key file
            - echo $BITBUCKET_SERVICE_ACCOUNT | base64 --decode --ignore-garbage > ./gcloud-api-key.json
            - gcloud auth activate-service-account --key-file gcloud-api-key.json
            - gcloud auth configure-docker us-docker.pkg.dev
            # Pushing the docker image
            - docker build . -t website
            - docker tag website us-docker.pkg.dev/<project_id>/website-nginx/website:latest
            - docker push us-docker.pkg.dev/<project_id>/website-nginx/website:latest
            - gcloud run deploy website --image us-docker.pkg.dev/<project_id>/website-nginx/website:latest --project <project_id> --region us-central1 --port 80 --memory 512Mi --cpu 1

However, it seems that the command gcloud auth configure-docker us-docker.pkg.dev just hangs in a frozen state without any feedback. This used to work before (the pipeline last ran about 10 days ago). There has been no recent changes on the Google Cloud Platform project.
I tried creating a new key for the service account. I've also double checked the permissions. It is strange as there has been no recent changes on the Google Cloud Platform project.

Have you tried replicating the series of commands from a known-working host such as e.g. Google Cloud Shell? Bitbucket may be swallowing some errors that would surface when run more interactively.

Hi @DazWilkin, thanks for your help.
I did try it out via the Google Cloud Shell after your suggestion, and the commands were working okay in the shell. Strangely, it is now also running okay in the Bitbucket pipeline again (without any changes to the pipeline or any of the services on the GCP project).
If it happens again, I will follow your recommendation to try in the shell again and progress from there
